# Unresolved reference: @SignInActivity

Tags: kotlin

```
    {
        val intent =Intent(this@SignInActivity::class.java)

   }
```

this@signInActitity is give giving an unresolved reference
I was trying to link sign up with google to my project and I encountered this

Comment: Did you mean `SignInActivity::class.java`?

Comment: Show more code.

Comment: I did the same thing from the tutorial video but mine is giving me error

Comment: You want ``Intent(this, SignInActivity::class.java)`` with a comma, not an @